# How should Openlayers RegularShape radius 1 and radius 2 be used to generate a star?

Tags: openlayers

The Openlayers documentation for ol.style.RegularShape says:

```
radius  number | undefined   Radius of a regular polygon.
radius1 number | undefined   Inner radius of a star.
radius2 number | undefined   Outer radius of a star.
```

My interpretation is that for a normal **polygon** (triangle, square, pentagon, etc) I would use `radius` but should NOT use either `radius1` or `radius2`.  And sure enough this works fine.

Similarly, I had interpreted this to mean that for a **star**, I should NOT use `radius` and that I should use both `radius1` and `radius2` and that `radius1` should be smaller than `radius2`.  However, this produced a rather odd-looking symbol in which I could see parts of a star, but it appeared to be cropped by a square mask.

To get the results I wanted (after examining the Openlayers example code) I ended up using `radius` and `radius2` with `radius2` being the smaller number!

The two versions of the javascript are below, with the only difference being the use of the various `radius(X)` parameters.

It appears that my understanding of the documentation is incorrect (or the documentation/implementation is broken).

I'd prefer to know why my new code works.  So could anyone please explain how the various `radius(X)` parameters are supposed to work, and help me to better understand the descriptions of all three?

This code produces a rather odd-looking symbol a bit like a star cutt off by a square mask:

[image: bad start]

```
new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#333333FF',
            width: 6.0
        }),
        radius1: 24,
        radius2: 60,
        points: 5
    })
})
```

This code produces a correct star:

[image: good start]

```
new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
            color: '#333333FF',
            width: 6.0
        }),
        radius: 60,
        radius2: 24,
        points: 5
    })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The documentation is incorrect. I created https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/pull/6604 with a fix.

You have to use either `radius1` or `radius` for the outer radius of a star, and `radius2` for the inner radius. The reason why your first example does not work is because the symbol size is determined from `radius` or `radius1`. If that is the smaller radius, the symbol size will not accommodate the whole star.

Comment: Thanks for this.   Very much appreciated.